# How to format the value of a checkbox Field using React Final Form Field Array?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

In React Final Form, we can use `format` or `parse` props for `text` type inputs in order to store a different value than the one specified, but this does not seems to work the same way with checkboxes.

Example:

```
<FieldArray name='test' initialValue={[true, false]}>
    <Field 
        component='input' 
        type='checkbox' 
        format={value => value ? 'foo' : null} 
        parse={value => value ? 'foo' : null}/>
    </Field>
</FieldArray>
```

in this example, the value to store will still be `true` or `false`, regardless the use of `format` and `parse`. Is it possible to format values from `[true, false]` to `["foo"]`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `format` function needs to convert it back into a boolean.

```
<Field
  name="employed"
  component="input"
  type="checkbox"
  format={v => v === "foo"}
  parse={v => (v ? "foo" : null)}
/>
```

But it *sounds* like you're wanting the already-built-in functionality of using checkboxes to manage membership in an array. To do that, you just specify a `value` prop to `<Field/>`. See the "Sauces" example:

[image: Edit quirky-voice-zruje]

☝️ Also includes the `format`/`parse` example.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks a lot, this helped us to solve the issue related to this. Thanks for your amazing job on this tool!